# FAST clock to run a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

What is the fastest possible clock that i can make? I need to run a command and it has to be SUPER FAST. I try putting the command block on repeat and always active, but that is still sort of slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a repeat command block will run the command on every single game tick. This is as fast as you can possibly run a clock, and runs at the same speed as a fill clock with less lag. There is no way to run a command block any faster.

Comment: every single game tick = 20 times per second

Comment: Like @Plagiatus said, 20 times per second, but slower when the server is not at its ideal speed (note: the single player game runs an internal server)

Answer (score -3):

Make an actual restone clock like so:
First place two blocks
Then, place redstone dust on top of them.
Then, place a torch on the long side
Place a repeater beside the torch so the torch powers it. Click it once.
Finally, connect the repeater and the dust on top.
Now hook in the command bloc to the clock!

Comment: This is slower than a repeating command block, and will cause more lag.